# Include backspace key in custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings, services

I want to make the keyboard shortcut for a Service I made ⌃⌥⌫ (Ctrl+Opt+Backspace); however, System Preferences doesn't let me do this. Is there a way I can include the key manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as this keyboard short cut is used as part of the operating system to perform backward word delete, this is where it deletes all the characters from the cursor position to the start of the current word, this is a part of macOS so it is likely protected.